# Extract string in a array of strings, split it and put into a new array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have a array of strings like this:

```
arr = ["\n<start>\n<exposition> <conflict> <escape> <conclusion>\t;\n", 
       "\n<exposition>\n<bad-guy> <insane-plan>\t;\n",
       "\n<conflict>\n<friendly-meeting> <female-interest> <danger>\t;\n"]
```

I want to extract every string in the array, split it using `\n` as the delimiter, then put it back to an array like this:

```
newArr = ["<start>",
          "<exposition> <conflict> <escape> <conclusion>",
          "<exposition>",
          "<bad-guy> <insane-plan>",
          "<conflict>",
          "<friendly-meeting> <female-interest> <danger>"]
```

I'm new to Ruby I tried to use `for` loop to iterate the array but it seems will eliminate all the Unix line ending then I have no delimiters to split the strings, and in the strings in `arr` they also have couple of extra characters `\t;` to remove.

Comment: one way, not very pretty. `arr.map { |s| s.scan(/\n(\<.*?\>)\n/) + s.scan(/(\<.*\>)\t\;\n/) }.flatten`

Comment: @sagarpandya82 kinda confusing whats inside the `scan()` ..... could you explain that to me?

Comment: Please wait for someone to answer (with explanation). The regex inside `scan()` is grabbing characters according to your specification. If you're unfamiliar with regex (sorry if you are) check out: https://regexone.com/ as a starter.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 your solution is pretty good why not answer it?

Comment: Please be more specific about the treatment of semicolons. For example, what should be the return value for the array `["<a;b>;<c>;\n<d>;\t<e>"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply achieve this with some regex:

```
arr.join.split /[\n\t;]+/
```

Here I'm joining the array of strings into one string and splitting it according to multiple conditions (newline, tab, and semicolon).

Comment: @Cyzenfar what if there is two `;\n` in here?  for example like `"["\n<conflict>\n<friendly-meeting> <female-interest> <danger>;\n;\n"]` , then the output should be `["<conflict>",
          "<friendly-meeting> <female-interest> <danger>", ""]`